# Timeout ssh sessions after inactivity?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, pci-dss

PCI-DSS 3.0 requirement 8.1.8 states: "If a session has been idle for more than 15 minutes, require the user to re-authenticate to re-activate the
terminal or session." Same was in PCI-DSS 2.0 requirement 8.5.15.

The first, and most obvious, way to deal with ssh sessions that are idling at the bash prompt is by enforcing a read-only, global `$TMOUT` of 900.  Unfortunately, that only covers sessions sitting at the bash prompt.  The spirit of the PCI spec would also require killing sessions running top/vim/etc.

I've considered writing a */1 cron job that parses the output of "/usr/bin/w" and kills the associated shell, but that seems like a blunt instrument.  Any ideas for something that would actually do what the spec requires and just lock the terminal?  I've looked at `away` and `vlock`; they both seem great for voluntarily locking your terminal, but I need a cron/daemon task that will enforce locking.

Comment: I'm really not trying to be pedantic, but I think you need to define 'idle' for us: idle = no user input? or idle = no output to user? The solutions required will be different.

Comment: idle == no user input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you put "exec screen -R" in .bash_profile and "idle 900 lockscreen" in .screenrc to solve this?  That'd automatically reattach to their screen session if it's still there and create a new one if it isn't, but lock the screen if it's idle for 900 seconds.

I believe users could disable the idle, though...

Alternately: just plain "exec screen" and also "autodetach off" in .screenrc so that their sessions die if they get disconnected.

Comment: Interesting idea; I may end up with something like this.  However I think I'd experience a rebel uprising if I forced everyone to start working inside screen.

Comment: With autodetach off, they'd basically never notice.  If you included something like 'defescape "^  "' (or at least to a more obscure control sequence than ^A) it'd be impossible or unlikely for them to actually treat screen like screen; they'd just see "screen" if they echo'd the TERM var, and even that you could change to vt100.

Comment: Is there a way to disconnect the users session not lock the screen and also run a script when the user is put into the screen that prints some messages/warnings?

Answer (score 4):

The following, added to your sshd config, will simply close the SSH connection after 15 minutes of inactivity:

```
ClientAliveInterval 900
ClientAliveCountMax 0
```

It is essential to include `ClientAliveCountMax 0` to prevent the server from sending "client alive messages" to the SSH client.

Comment: As freiheit already pointed out: This simply doesn't do what's wanted at all. The ClientAliveInterval causes the sshd server to (essentially) send a ping through the ssh channel to see if the client is still there. It's not useful for idling out the user.

Comment: It worked for me. Did you test it? If so, did you restart the ssh daemon? Did you restart your SSH session after restarting the daemon? Note that `man sshd_config` indicates _This option applies to protocol version 2 only_ for both `ClientAliveCountMax` and `ClientAliveInterval`

Answer (score 3):

Under BSD i'm using [idled by Michael P. Crider](http://www.freshports.org/sysutils/idled)

Quote from description

> Idled is a daemon that runs on a
>   machine to keep an eye on current
>   users.  If users have been idle for
>   too long, or have been logged on for
>   too long, or have logged in too many
>   times, it will warn them and log them
>   out appropriately.

I think you also can find it in linux repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Does sshd's IdleTimeout setting do what you want? I haven't test it with users using top, but it should work for vim or things which aren't sending data.

Comment: +1 -- This is my thought, as well.  Set "ClientAliveInterval 900" (15 min = 900s) and "ClientAliveCountMax 0" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config and restart sshd and that should do it.

Comment: That timeout can be easily circumvented by a client application sending "keep-alive" packets though.

Comment: This simply doesn't do what's wanted at all.  The ClientAliveInterval causes the sshd server to (essentially) send a ping through the ssh channel to see if the client is still there.  It's not useful for idling out the user.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer here is

export TMOUT=900

in .bash_profile

(invoking screen isnt a direct way to deal with this problem)

http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash